# Poisson and Binomial RVs

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Compute $E[e^{tX}]$ as a function of t ∈ R when 
(1) X is Poisson λ, 
(2) X is Binomial n, p. [Hint: you may find the Binomial Theorem to be useful].

The PMF of Poisson is
$$
p_x(k)=e^{-λ}λ^k/k!
$$

I know if X is Poisson, E[X] = λ. So how would i incorporate that into $E[e^{tX}]$?

Comment: Just use the definition for the expected value

Comment: @orange Do you mean first calculate the PMF and then calculate E[X]? Because if so, I'm confused how to calculate PMF. For Poisson, do I plug (e^tX) into k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be poisson $\text{Poi}(\lambda)$ distributed. Then for the moment generating function
$$m_X(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{tX}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk} \mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk} \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k}\frac{(e^t \lambda)^k}{k!}$$
The last sum is the series representation of $e^{(e^t\lambda)}$, so
$$m_X(t)=e^{-\lambda}e^{e^t\lambda}=e^{\lambda (e^t-1)}.$$

Similarly let $X$ be binomially distributed with parameters $(n,p)$- We have
$$m_X(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{tX}=\sum_{k}e^{tx}\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{k}e^{kt}{n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=\sum_{k}{n \choose k}(pe^t)^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$$
Using the binomial theorem:
$$\mathbb{E}e^{tX}=(1-p+pe^t)^n$$

Comment: thank you for this. in the last step, what does the 's' represent? it wasn't in the problem before so where did it come from?

Comment: @Sra if you reload the page, the answer should be typo free now.